# Surface shading in Solid Viewport is broken: blender

Tags: shaders, lighting

I consider myself quite experienced w/ Blender, yet have never encountered the problem, as seen in the image, before.

[image: Broken Lighting of Surface in Solid Viewport]

Here are some details, hopefully to provide more clarity concerning my problem:

- The mesh is shaded Flat, yet it has notably incorrect 'smoothed' shading.
- The mesh is divided into individual Islands. These Islands do intersect w/ each other.
- The most recent Islands suffer the most.
- I have attempted to append the mesh into an older version of blender (2.93), and the problem persisted.
- I have ensured all normals face outward, with no irregularities.
- Some doubles do exist throughout the mesh, only because of the aforementioned division into Islands.

Does anyone know how I might fix this?

Edit: Here is the offending Mesh: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19jdwPf6Y-wI-yJB4AzF5jImSvhtUT7j3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide blend file to check it out

Comment: If this is a model imported from another source, go to mesh properties > Normals > Clear custom split normals

Answer (score 1):

The model has custom per-face-corner normals that are overriding the flat-shaded normals.  You can discard these, as Gorgious offered, by Clear Custom Split Normals in properties/object data/geometry, or you can tell Blender not to use them by disabling Autosmooth in properties/object data/normals.